# Cannot install catkin-tools on Debian buster due to Python version requirement

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS Noetic on a Debian Buster system, which is [listed as a supported platform](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation).

However, I cannot install packages (like `python3-catkin-tools`) that depend on the `python3-osrf-pycommon` package because it requires Python 3.8, and Buster provides Python 3.7.

```
$ sudo apt install -s -o Debug::pkgDepCache::AutoInstall=true python3-catkin-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
  Installing python3-osrf-pycommon as Depends of python3-catkin-tools
    python3-osrf-pycommon:amd64 Depends on python3:any:any < none @un H > (>= 3.8~) can't be satisfied!
```

Though `python3-osrf-pycommon` is listed on the package index as [not being supported on Noetic](https://index.ros.org/p/osrf_pycommon/github-osrf-osrf_pycommon/#noetic)...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395610/cannot-install-catkin-tools-on-debian-buster-due-to-python-version-requirement/) by [rgov](https://answers.ros.org/users/45623/rgov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2022-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rgov](https://answers.ros.org/users/45623/rgov/) on 2022-02-03**:
I think this was a regression introduced in [this pull request](https://github.com/osrf/osrf_pycommon/pull/66) and hopefully it can be resolved by publishing the right package version for Buster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Until this bug is resolved it should be possible to do:

```
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-osrf-pycommon/python3-osrf-pycommon_1.0.2-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i python3-osrf-pycommon_1.0.2-1_all.deb
```

Then continue installing the original package (e.g., `python3-catkin-tools`).

---

Originally posted by [rgov](https://answers.ros.org/users/45623/rgov/) with karma: 130 on 2022-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0